# What is the difference between metafile and enhanced metafile?

Tags: microsoft-office

Simple scenario:

Go into Excel.  Create a graph.  Select it, and copy it.  Now go into powerpoint. If you go to the "Paste Special" menu, there are options for Picture (Windows Metafile) and Picture (Enhanced Metafile).

What is the difference?

Comment: Discussion here...http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1899038.php

Comment: Design of EMF...http://www.herdsoft.com/ti/davincie/imex1xo3.htm

Comment: EMF and printing...http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/0,,sid9_gci213583,00.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile)

> Windows Metafile (WMF) is a graphics file format on Microsoft Windows systems, originally designed in the early 1990s. Windows Metafiles are intended to be portable between applications and may contain both vector graphics and bitmap components.
>
> Essentially, a WMF file stores a list of function calls that have to be issued to the Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) layer in order to display an image on screen
>
> In 2007 Enhanced Metafile (EMF) a newer 32-bit version with additional commands appeared. EMF is also used as a graphics language for printer drivers. The last(?) version of EMF, 4.0, appeared in 2008.
>
> With the release of Windows XP, the Enhanced Metafile Format Plus Extensions (EMF+) format was introduced. EMF+ provides a way to serialize calls to the GDI+ API in the same way that WMF/EMF stores calls to GDI.

So essentially EMF is a newer better updated version of WMF. I suppose WMF is still around for back portability.

Answer (score 0):

**in short:**

EMF ... more features

WMF ... smaller diskspace

**Description:**
EMF is the enhanced Version of WMF, and supports more features (e.g. dotted line) and therefore converting to EMF works more often than to wmf, however when saving a file with Inkscape EMF needs about 5 times the disk-space of WMF.